# is it possible to mock/fake an extension method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, fakeiteasy

I'm using a controller extension, and I tried to mock it using FakeItEasy (v 1.7.4) like this:

```
A.CallTo(() => controller.RenderView(A<string>.Ignored,A<object>.Ignored,null)).Returns("");
```

but I get this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Object.GetType()
at FakeItEasy.Creation.ProxyGeneratorSelector.MethodCanBeInterceptedOnInstance(MethodInfo method, Object callTarget, ref String failReason)
at FakeItEasy.Configuration.DefaultInterceptionAsserter.AssertThatMethodCanBeInterceptedOnInstance(MethodInfo method, Object callTarget)
at FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationManager.CallTo(Expression`1 callSpecification)
```

Answer (score 15):

This is not possible. Proxying/intercepting libraries used by FakeItEasy (and other popular free frameworks, like Moq or RhinoMocks) don't allow interception of static methods (static properties, sealed classes and non-virtual instance methods in fact). And extension method is just a kind of static method.

You can take a look at [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) or [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking/features.aspx), which do have such functionality.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want a free option, Moles also allows mocking of static methods: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/

Comment: This may be coming to FakeItEasy. How soon, I'm not sure - https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/90

Answer (score 3):

If the extension method is declared in a separate assembly, you could link in a replacement assembly with the same namespace.

You'd have to replace any other required types from this assembly too, though.

Comment: +1: that's really interesting solution as long as you don't have to replace too much.

Comment: @jimmy_keen Thanks! It's basically the link seam from [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052).

Answer (score -2):

In FakeItEasy you can create it as a strict mock and then configure the static method

http://hocke.blogspot.com.ar/2011/03/extension-method-for-creating-strict.html

Comment: this has absolutely nothing to do with faking extension methods. Your google-foo has let you down here