# How do I use moq to assert a function is called in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to learn how to use Moq to do unit testing with C#. I setup a simple class, BasicMath that has a function `int Multiply(int a, int b)`, the body just returns a * b. I have another class called AdvancedMath which has a function 'int Square(int a)', the body calls Multiply(a,a) and returns the result.

I am trying to write a simple test for AdvancedMath.Square that will assert that BasicMath.Multiply is called with the correct values. I understand that you cannot do this with ordinary public function so I made the functions virtual, but I am still having trouble. Can someone explain to me how this is done? Neither class has any constructor other than the default empty constructor.

Here is my attempt:

```
class test_Advanced_Functions
{
    [Test]
    public void test_SquareFunction_Should_return_correct_result()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<BasicFunctions> mock = new Mock<BasicFunctions>();
        AdvancedFunctions af = new AdvancedFunctions();

        // Act
        int result = af.Square(5);

        //Assert
        mock.Verify(d => d.Multiply(5, 5), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Moq to determine if a method is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347818/using-moq-to-determine-if-a-method-is-called)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - The difference is that in question referenced the method under test takes the other class as one of it's parameters. It should be possible to assert a function is called without forcing that you pass the object in as a parameter... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `AdvancedMath` derives from `BasicMath` then you can test that with Moq when `Multiply` is virtual:

```
var mock = new Mock<AdvancedMath>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Multiply(2, 2)).Returns(4);
mock.Object.Square(2);
mock.VerifyAll();
```

If you use `BasicMath` within `AdvancedMath` (ie. if `Multiply` is static and is invoked directly from `Square`), then testing such interaction ***is not possible*** with Moq. To see why, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9064566/343266).

However, doing behavior based verification in such simple case doesn't seem right. You need to answer yourself a question: *"what do I want to test?"*. That `Square` **works** or that it calls some methods? This test (what you plan to do now), only delegates responsibility to `Multiply`, assuming it works. Your `Square` implementation might change in multiple ways (as in, not using `Multiply`) and it will break your test - it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

`Moq` cannot modify behavior of instances that it has not created.

You should write your classes to be unit-testable by practicing dependency injection. Since `AdvancedFunctions` apparently depends on `BasicFunctions`, it should have a `BasicFunctions` passed in as a constructor argument, rather than `new`ing one up on its own.