# RhinoMocks - Getting the value passed into an Indexer (this[])

Tags: unit-testing, arguments, rhino-mocks

I need to find out the value passed into an indexer.

My code (c#) that I need to test is as follows:

```
string cacheKey = GetCacheKey(cacheKeyRequest);
string cachedValue = myCache[cacheKey] as string;
```

So, I need to be able to identify the value of the "cacheKey" that was passed into the indexer.

I have attempted this using a Mock of the cache object:

```
var cache = MockRepository.GenerateMock<WebDataCache>();
```

The idea being that after the code had executed, I would query the mock to identify the value that had been passed into the indexer:

```
var actualCacheKey = cache.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(a => a["somevalue"], opt => opt.IgnoreArguments())[0][0].ToString();
```

This gives me a compilation error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

I saw one suggestion to make this a function in the following way:

```
var actualCacheKey = cache.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(a => a["somevalue"] = null, opt => opt.IgnoreArguments())[0][0].ToString();
```

This now compiles,but throws a run-time InvalidOperationException: No expectations were setup to be verified, ensure that the method call in the action is a virtual (C#) / overridable (VB.Net) method call.

Any suggestions?  [Am using RhinoMocks.3.6.1]

Many thanks in advance

Griff

PS - I have previously posted this in http://groups.google.com/group/rhinomocks but after several days the view-count remains depressingly low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception tells you exactly what is happening:

> InvalidOperationException: No expectations were setup to be verified, **ensure** that the **method** call in the action is a **virtual** (C#) / overridable (VB.Net) method call.

Which means, in order for Rhino to properly work (or, in order for Castle to generate [working proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796367/343266)) your indexer has to be virtual. If you can't make it so, Rhino won't help you in this situation.

Once you make your indexer virtual, it is simple task:

```
var cache = MockRepository.GenerateMock<WebDataChache>();
cache.Expect(c => c["SomeKey"]).Returns("SomeValue");

// perform actual test

cache.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

This ensures that cache is accessed with `["SomeKey"]`. If key value will be different, test will fail at `VerifyAllExpectations` line.